# run the chef client automatically only when i upload my cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

I am new to chef. I want to know how to run the chef client automatically only when I made any changes (like cookbook version) in the cookbook and again upload it (it means run the chef client only one time for one cookbook). I know the command for run the chef-client at particular intervals. But I don't need it. Because even I didn't change anything it took the cookbook and run it. I need to the run the chef client automatically only changes made in the cookbook. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the wrong path I think (at least not the path chef is done for)

The main idea with chef is to use idempotent resources, it means that you can run chef periodically and it will ensure the system is in the state wanted by the cookbooks recipes.

It will not restart an already started service if there's no reason too (no configuration change triggering a restart notification for exemple).

The idea behind this is to ensure you don't have manual configuration change on your server which will be forgotten with time.

You should focus on your cookbooks to be sure they are idempotent and avoid as possible working with ad-hoc chef runs.

If you want this anyway the command line is `chef-client -o 'cookbook::recipe'` to override the runlist and run only one recipe of one cookbook. If the recipe is the default.rb you can omit it from the command line.